# Facebook Like Button XFBML comment not working

Tags: facebook, xfbml

**Update**: Read the comments to the item marked as the answer below for the full answer.

I am implementing a Like button from Facebook per this document: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like

I am using the XFBML version so that users can add comments when they click on the Like button. I have imported the Facebook JavaScript SDK an am using a valid App ID. The button appears and I am able to "Like" the page, but I am never prompted for comments.

Is anybody else running into these issues? Anybody know of a fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before I had inserted the correct `appId` in the `FB.init()` call to initialize the Facebook javascript SDK, the button appeared, I was able to "Like" the page like you, but saw no comment box either.

When I inserted the appId, but hosted the page locally, I got an error message saying that the page could not be reached (from Facebook's servers).

Finally, hosting the page on a public server made the buttons behave as expected: with comment box for the XFBML version, and without comment box for the Iframe.

Hope that helps...

Comment: So it must be something to do with my App ID then. I am using a valid App ID that I own. Do I need to configure my application in some special way to get it to work? Maybe whitelist my server?

Comment: I didn't do anything other than serving the page on the domain that I had registered the appId for.  It was a brand new appId.

Comment: I must be setting my app Id up in the wrong place or way. I go to facebook.com/developers and add an application. I'm never actually prompted for a domain - where do I put in this domain? Thanks so much for your replies.

Comment: Got it figured! On your app page click "Edit Settings". Then click "Connect". Make sure that the "Connect URL" matches the public domain that the button will be on. This may have been obvious for some, but I couldn't find any documentation that mentions this...

Answer (score 2):

add this style and the comment box will be hidden after you click like.

```
.fb_edge_widget_with_comment span.fb_edge_comment_widget iframe.fb_ltr {
      display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

retailevovled is right. I've just found this tutorial which is a bit more detailed (German, but you can use Google Translate): http://www.be24.at/blog/entry/639312

Answer (score 0):

Create an app for this specific implementation, then it will work:
http://developers.facebook.com/setup/

(I too first used an 'old' app-id with the same problems you described.)